# Permit of submitting an input value only when it fulfils a pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make a list of items, double-clicking on one item makes it editable. Currently, while editing an item, clicking outside (ie, `blur`) or enter by keyboard submits the new value.

I want to be able to submit the new change **only when it is not empty or fulfil a pattern (eg, a file name with `.`)**.

I tried `ng-required="true"`, it did not work.

Does anyone know how to set this restriction?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pasodiwoxe/1/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    input {
      font-size: 20px;
      border:none;
      background-color:transparent;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="{{item.name}}" ng-blur='eEditable = -1' ng-readonly='$index !== eEditable' ng-dblclick="eEditable = $index" ng-keypress="keypress($event)" ng-required="true"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{ name: "item #1" }, { name: "item #2" }, { name: "item #3" }];
      $scope.eEditable = -1;
      $scope.keypress = function ($event) {
        if ($event.keyCode === 13)
          $event.target.blur()
      }
    }])
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1:** the existing answers suggest to use `form`, but I don't want to use `form` or `submit` button.

One solution would be verifying the new value in a `myBlur` function: if the pattern is not satisfied, we could set the focus back to the input field and let users modify the value again. Here is another [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vebudezeke/2/edit?html,output).

Does anyone know how to **set the focus back to the input field**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to set the focus back to the input field?

If you are validating the inputs in the ngKeypress event you can use the $event.
If the validation fails, set focus back to the input with

```
angular.element($event.currentTarget).focus();
```

Comment: indeed, in `ngKeypress` we could do that... but how could we do this while mouse bluring?

Comment: For blur you could use the NgBlur event which also presents the event in $event https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Comment: @SoftTimur see my comment on blur

Comment: Here is a modified [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yefexilaki/1/edit?html,output), the satisfaction condition is `=== "ok"`. One problem is, the satisfied item is not read-only any more; we could edit it by just one click rather than double click. Do you know how to amend this?

Comment: @SoftTimur I've added the solution in plunker, its a start. Check this out https://plnkr.co/edit/Rd1hJiLAS95OE7qgEg6P?p=preview

Comment: It works, though I don't think `if(!$scope.hasError)` in `$scope.mydbClick` (thus the use of `$scope.hasError`) is necessary...

Comment: @SoftTimur yes, remove it. I had some trouble with the ng-readonly directive with the dbclick so tried different approaches. I think the expression in the ng-readonly was the key here.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-pattern with a regular expression

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input" ng-pattern="regex" />
```

I found this site helpful making regex http://regexr.com/

Comment: yes, but Bens answer is more detailed you do need to put the input in a form and ng-required should work then.

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent submission by using a `<form>` with `ng-submit`, `ng-required`, and, `ng-pattern` directives:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitClicked($event, myForm)">
   <input type="text" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/.)/">
   <input type="submit">
</form>

$scope.submitClicked = function($event, form) {
     if (!form.$valid) {
          $event.preventDefault();
     }
}
```